# react native elements right arrow icon not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I am using the `react-native-elements` library and I'm trying to show the `Entypo` right arrow icon in one of my components, but the name 'arrow-right' isn't working. Instead, I see a question mark.

```
<Icon name="arrow-right" size={20} color="black" />
```

I got the icon name from here: https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/.

[image: output]

Comment: Have you imported the icon first?

Comment: import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'..Here is it

Comment: How you point to the icon?

Comment: I thought setting the NAME parameter will set it.

Comment: No, in place you want to use icon put {Icon}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing `Icon` from `react-native-elements` is actually the correct way to do it as you get access to the additional props `react-native-elements` provides (Like the `raised` prop for example). The problem was that you needed to specify a `type`. The `type` prop determines which icon set will be used.

```
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'

<Icon name="arrow-right" size={20} color="black" type="entypo" />
```

All available icon sets and properties are listed here: https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/icon.